# Is there a way to return a method parameter names in ruby

Tags: ruby, reflection, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Argument Names In Ruby Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622324/getting-argument-names-in-ruby-reflection)

Is it possible to get the parameter names of a method ?

Example with:

```
def method_called(arg1, arg2)
  puts my_method.inspect
end
```

I would like to know what method (my_method) should I call to get the following output:

```
["arg1", "arg2"]
```

Comment: Somebody has posted the same question here is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622324/getting-argument-names-in-ruby-reflection

Answer (score 10):

In Ruby 1.9.2, you can trivially get the parameter list of any `Proc` (and thus of course also of any `Method` or `UnboundMethod`) with `Proc#parameters`:

```
def foo(a, b=nil, *c, d, &e); end
p method(:foo).parameters
  # => [[:req, :a], [:opt, :b], [:rest, :c], [:req, :d], [:block, :e]]
```

The format is an array of pairs of symbols: type (required, optional, rest, block) and name.

For the format you want, try

```
method(:foo).parameters.map(&:last).map(&:to_s)
  # => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Good news that this exist for Ruby 1.9.2, I will take note of that. But for the moment I am using 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

## 1

If you are on Ruby 1.9.1 you can use the [MethoPara](http://github.com/Genki/MethoPara/) gem. This allows you to do the following:

```
def method_called(arg1, arg2)
  method(caller[0][/`([^']*)'/, 1].to_sym).parameters
end
```

## 2

You can use the approach proposed by Michael Grosser at his [blog](http://pragmatig.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/ruby-monkey-reflection-to-get-method-parameter-names/).

## 3

[Merb Action Args](http://github.com/wycats/merb/tree/master/merb-action-args)

Answer (score 0):

Within a method, you can get the names you've given the arguments by calling `local_variables` at the beginning (since no other local variables will have been defined at the time).

However, I don't think any good will come of this for any purpose besides *maybe* logging info. If you have a specific goal in mind, we could probably find something more idiomatic.

Comment: It's useful for loggin but it's for console usage. When I am in a irb session and I want to call a specific method that I don't remember tts parameters. I would like to have a easy way of knowing them without going to the source code or using ri.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the value for the default values, too, there's the "arguments" gem

```
$ gem install rdp-arguments
$ irb
>> require 'arguments'
>> require 'test.rb' # class A is defined here
>> Arguments.names(A, :go)
```

Comment: This doesn't work beyond Ruby 1.9.2 it seems.