# Inject a line of code into an existing method at runtime

Tags: ruby

At runtime, I would like to inject a line of code at the - `# <-- Injection point`

```
class A

  def some_method(a, b = 1, *c, d: 1, **e)
    # <-- Injection point
    
    # Code that does stuff
    puts a
    puts b
    puts c
    puts d
    puts e
  end
end
```

The reason I need this is so that I can use the [Ruby Tracepoint Class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/TracePoint.html) to extract some run time information about the method signature.

Specifically the default parameter values in `b = 1` and `d: 1`

I have looked at this question [Inspect the default value for optional parameter in ruby's method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751724/how-can-i-inspect-what-is-the-default-value-for-optional-parameter-in-rubys-met) where a useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34753714/473923) exists but want to inject the code that they suggest, dynamically.

I already have existing code that can extracts method signatures from ruby classes.

#### Example

Given this Class, which is defined with lots of methods using various parameterized signatures.

```
class A
  def d;                                  end
  def e(a);                               end
  def f(a, b = 1);                        end
  def g(a, b = 1, c = 2);                 end
  def h(*a);                              end
  def i(a, b, *c);                        end
  def j(**a);                             end
  def k(a, *b, **c);                      end
  def l(a, *b, **c, &d);                  end
  def m(a:);                              end
  def n(a:, b: 1);                        end
  def p?;                                 end
  def z(a, b = 1, *c, d: 1, **e);         end
end
```

I can run the following code to extract signature information. Unfortunately, it fails to resolve the `default` parameter or named values.

```
class_definition = MethodSignatures.new(A.new)
class_definition.print
```

#### Issues are Red

[image: co]

Comment: are you able to define those methods in a module? if so then you could simply redefine them in your class as well, and you could call super on them so you could: (i) add the injection and then retain the function that the methods were meanth to perform in the model. Alternatively, are you ok with renaming those methods and then adding the injection in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason I need this is so that I can use the Ruby Tracepoint Class to extract some run time information about the method signature.
>
> Specifically the default parameter values in b = 1 and d: 1

`TracePoint` allows you to fetch information without patching the method. You just have to set up a `:call` hook and then call the method:

```
TracePoint.trace(:call) do |tp|
  tp.parameters.each do |type, name|
    value = tp.binding.local_variable_get(name)
    puts format('%8s: %s = %s', type, name, value.inspect)
  end
end

A.new.some_method(123)
```

Output: (omitting the method's output)

```
     req: a = 123
     opt: b = 1
    rest: c = []
     key: d = 1
 keyrest: e = {}
```

Comment: Thanks again Stefan, (2 days in a row), this did exactly what I needed. I just added `next unless tp.self.is_a?(A)` to remove the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Ruby v2.0 one would redefine `A#some_method` after aliasing the original `A#some_method`.

```
class A
  def some_method(a, b, c)
    puts a
    puts b
    puts c
  end
end
```

```
A.public_send(:alias_method, :old_some_method, :some_method)
A.define_method(:some_method) do |a,b,c|
  puts "a=#{a}, b=#{b}, c=#{c}"
  old_some_method(a,b,c)
end
```

```
A.new.some_method(1,2,3)
a=1, b=2, c=3
1
2
3
```

A better way, however, is to define the new method `A#some_method` in a module and then [Module#prepend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) that module to the class `A`. `prepend` made its debut in Ruby v2.0.

```
module M
  def some_method(a,b,c)
    puts "a=#{a}, b=#{b}, c=#{c}"
    super
  end
end
```

```
A.prepend M
```

```
A.new.some_method(1,2,3)
a=1, b=2, c=3
1
2
3
```

`A.prepend M` gives the methods of `M` priority over those of `A`.

```
A.ancestors
  #=> [M, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

shows this to be the case and also explains the role of `super` in the method `M#some_method`.

Comment: thanks for the information Cary, unfortunately, this will not work for my use-case because do not have access to the code for altering, the idea is to reverse engineer signatures from GEMs and other code that I might not have easy access to.