# Is it possible to get the default value for keyword arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am looking to get the default values for a function with keyword arguments.
Example:

```
def some_method(foo: 1, bar: 2)
end
```

My expected output would be something like

```
{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }
```

The [parameters](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-parameters) method defined on method only provides parameter names.

Comment: I don't think there is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751724

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keys, but not the values, because they aren't actually set until the method is actually invoked. You can get the method's parameters using [Method#parameters](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Method.html#method-i-parameters). For example, using your example code from above:

```
method(:some_method).parameters
#=> [[:key, :foo], [:key, :bar]]
```

However, the :foo and :bar keys aren't actually set until the method is run, so there's no way to get the "value" except possibly to introspect the method definition itself.

Comment: I can use introspection to do it, but I am having difficulty coming up with a good solution.

Comment: @MarkRamasco If you're running from a file, you might be able to do it with RBS and/or TypeProf, or simply grepping for the method definition and parsing it. However, from a REPL, you can't access the source in irb, and would probably need to hijack stdout from pry (which is generally a bad idea) to match against output from show-source or show-method. Since I explained that Ruby doesn't set the default arguments until invoked, you might get better answers if you explain your use case; this may be an X/Y problem.

Comment: Without going into too much detail, I had to write an adapter around a custom legacy framework for writing tests. This was built on years of work, so it's not a scenario that we can easily change. Essentially, the framework allows someone to write a description that uses string interpolation to fill in values from the test input parameters. This is one of those scenarios where everything is wrong, but I needed to find a work around solution.

I ended up with a really janky work around where I use [sorcerer](https://rubygems.org/gems/sorcerer/versions/1.0.2) to parse the source.