# How to print a method's parameter names

Tags: ruby, printing, parameters

Is there a quick way to output the possible parameter names of a ruby method?

For example:

```
def my_method(param1, param2, param3, ...)
  # stuff
end

puts get_params("my_method")
```

which would output something like:

```
param1
param2
param3
...
```

Thanks!

Oh, btw I'm on ree-1.8.7...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Argument Names In Ruby Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622324/getting-argument-names-in-ruby-reflection) - the original question asks slightly more, but Jorg Mittag's answer answers your question.

Comment: even the first response has some pretty helpful insight, thanks man

Comment: There's a couple of other duplicates as well: [Is there a way to return a method parameter names in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2452077/#2452322), [Reflection on method parameters in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3456827/#3460072), [Any ruby library to inspect what are the arguments that a certain methods take?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6420695/#6425175) and [How do i get the names or arguments inside the method definition?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7136868/). I guess it would be time to add some kind of search feature to StackOverflow, maybe a textbox in the top right corner?

Comment: Sorry, I should have edited my post earlier. I'm on ree-1.8.7 which doesn't have Method#parameters, as mentioned below. ;)I think I can get by with local_Variables, though not ideal.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
class A
  def my_method(param1, param2, param3)
    # stuff
  end
end

A.instance_method(:my_method).parameters # => [[:req, :param1],[:req, :param2],[:req, :param3]]

A.instance_method(:my_method).parameters.collect { |p| p[1] } # => [:param1, param2, param3]
```

And if you do it on the irb console, as in your example:

```
>> def my_method(param1, param2, param3)
>>   # stuff
>> end
=> nil

>> def get_params(method_name)
>>   self.class.instance_method(method_name.to_sym).parameters.collect { |p| p[1] }.each { |name| puts name }
>> end
=> nil

>> get_params(:my_method)
param1
param2
param3
=> [:param1, :param2, :param3]
```

(Copy/pasted from my irb console.)

Comment: It should be know that whilst this is the best answer, Method#parameters is 1.9 only

Comment: Exactly 1.9.2. Ruby 1.9.1 doesn't contain it (at least my version ;) )

Comment: I'm stuck using ree-1.8.7, which doesn't look like it has #parameters either. This is definitely a solution though, but is there a way without that method?

Comment: +1 .. just re-read the question.. he is asking for the names of the params :)