# Ruby: How to get the default value of optional proc arguments

Tags: ruby, function, reflection, default-value, optional-parameters

Let's say I have a proc/lambda/block/method/etc like so:

```
2.1.2 :075 > procedure = Proc.new { |a, b=2, *c, &d| 42 }
 => #<Proc:0x000000031fcd10@(irb):75>
```

I know I can find out the names of the parameters with:

```
2.1.2 :080 > procedure.parameters
 => [[:opt, :a], [:opt, :b], [:rest, :c], [:block, :d]]
```

But how do I go about getting the value that a given optional parameter would assume if it is **not** given?

---

PS: Yes. I know this has been asked/answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622324/getting-argument-names-in-ruby-reflection), but the previous solution requires the use of the `merb` gem, which is actually slightly misleading. `merb` itself depended on the `methopara` gem (unless you're on JRuby or MRI, which I am not) which itself provided the feature at the time the question was answered.

Sadly, presently, `methopara` appears to be abandonware. Also, it only ever supported ruby 1.9 (and not even the latest version thereof), so I'm looking for a solution that works for current ruby versions.

Comment: I think this is nearly impossible, you must take in account that the so called `default` value can be any kind of executable code and it will be executed every time you call it.

Comment: @hakcho, very good catch. (I totally lost track of this account and used an entirely different approach since I posted this.) Still, it would be nice to have programmatic access to that value (or routine, if it is one).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the proc / lambda was defined in a file, you can use the `source_location` method to find the location of that file and the line number it was defined on.

```
2.2.0 (main):0 > OH_MY_PROC.source_location
=> [
  [0] "sandbox/proc.rb",
  [1] 1
]
```

With some help from `File.readlines` we can make a short method that when passed a proc / lambda can spit out the source line it was defined on.

```
def view_def proc_lambda
  location = proc_lambda.source_location
  File.readlines(location[0])[location[1]-1]
end
```

In action it looks something like this

```
2.2.0 (main):0 > view_def OH_MY_PROC
=> "OH_MY_PROC = Proc.new { |a, b=2, *c, &d| 42 }\n"
2.2.0 (main):0 > view_def OH_MY_LAMBDA
=> "OH_MY_LAMBDA = ->(a, b=2, *c, &d) { 42 }\n"
```

If you want to do the same for methods it becomes a bit more involved. In that case I recommend reading this blog post from the Pragmatic Studio blog: ["View Source" On Ruby Methods](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/13/view-source-ruby-methods)

Comment: might as well use merb. source_location is great when you rescue an exception and want to open the proc in your text editor

Comment: @rivenfall Please see original post. Merb is not an option due to an abandoned dependency.

Comment: @brownmike I had been looking for a way to do this without parsing source code on my own, but thanks for the idea. In any case I have since gone a different way.