# How can I get the default values for named arguments for a method?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have this method:

```
def person(name: "calvin")
  ...
end
```

I want to find the *default value* for param `name`. How would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. Why are you looking to do this? You could declare that as a constant external to the method.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622324/getting-argument-names-in-ruby-reflection

Comment: @Casper, are you suggesting the use of the Merb gem?

Comment: unclear for me. What it is __default value__?

Comment: Don't you mean, "Can I do that?"?

Comment: You're right, I mean "can I do that". I looked into the Merb code, but it is hairy. I was wondering if there's a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no list of parameter defaults, a default value is code that is executed.

```
def foo(t=Time.now)
  p t
end

foo  #2015-04-20 19:43:54 +0200
sleep 1
foo  #2015-04-20 19:43:55 +0200
```

Comment: Good answer. Here's another simple example, where the default value depends on the number of times the method's been called: `@b = 0; def a(t=@b) @b += 1 end`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this will help, but `person.send(:local_variables)` might be a good starting point.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Neither does `method(:person).parameters #=> [[:key, :name]] 
`.