# Getting the default value of named or optional parameter

Tags: ruby

I have a method that looks like this:

```
class A
  def my_method(a: 'key value', b = 'opt value')
    # ...
  end
end
```

Using reflection, I can get the parameter names like this:

```
A.new.method(:my_method).parameters
# => [[:key, :a], [:opt, :b]]
```

How can I get the default values of these parameters without invoking `my_method`?

Comment: It looks like this can be done using a Merb's action-args library. Take a look at this answer and see if it gets you what you want? As Antti suggests, I would cherry pick what you want from Merb's source code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/625222/227397

Comment: Just a nitpick but I think optional params need to go first in the argument list, so `my_method(b = 'opt', a: 'key')`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: @spickermann I'm trying to get the default values.

Comment: @Max : Sure, but why do you need the default values? What do you want to do with this information? This approach seems to violate the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). And qour question sounds like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: I'm just playing around with Ruby and I'm curious how one would accomplish this. I have no greater problem to solve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. I can't find the thread right now, but matz has explicitly said that this is by design. The problem is that the default value is an arbitrary expression, and since everything in Ruby is an expression, it can be anything.

For example, what about this:

```
def foo(bar = if rand < 0.5 then Time.now else rand end)
```

What would your proposed method return here?

Basically, you have two choices:

- Evaluate the default value expression. This means you will get *some* value, but that doesn't tell you much about what the real expression is.
- Don't evaluate the default value expression, by packaging it up in a `Proc`. But there's no way to get the expression out of a `Proc` again.

So, either way, you don't actually get any useful information.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.