# Is there a way to explicitly evoke the default keyword argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a function with a default keyword argument

```
def foo(bar: "baz")
  bar
end
```

Is there a way to call `foo` with the keyword argument but still invoke whatever the default is? For example, a way to make this work?

```
foo(bar: :default)
#=> "baz"
```

Alternatively, is there a way to see what the default arguments of a method are from within that method?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier than you think. Just don't specify it:

```
foo
# => "baz"
```

Defaults are applied only to those values that are not explicitly specified. As a note this means that in this case you're overriding it:

```
foo(bar: nil)
# => nil
```

This is why I generally try to write methods of this form:

```
def foo(bar: nil)
  bar or 'baz'
end
```

That way you can be assured that no matter what you get you return a value.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to explicitly call for whatever the default is, or see what the default is even when an argument is passed in?

Setting the default to nil and then overriding with an or statement seems like it may be the best way to go if it's not possible, thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's not part of the core Ruby standard, but there are ways of doing it if you absolutely must know. I'd strongly recommend not using any [hacks of that sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622324/getting-argument-names-in-ruby-reflection). Often the `=nil` or `x: nil` notation means "optional" to anyone using your library and there's an expectation a default will be applied. This default can be documented manually, or maybe it's not relevant as it doesn't concern the caller so long as they get their expected results. The *Do What I Mean* principle applies here, where close enough counts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I'm testing the limits of reasonability where it comes to metaprogramming in Ruby. I'm hoping nobody will ever need to touch this method :)

Comment: There's a limit to how clever your code can get before that starts to bite you and become harmful. It's like how [Angular](https://angularjs.org) looks for particular argument names on the `function` passed in so it knows how to respond, and that sounds great until a code minifier goes and mangles them all.

Answer (score 1):

tadman already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139564/is-there-a-way-to-explicitly-evoke-the-default-keyword-argument-in-ruby/39140146#comment65623894_39139630) that you cannot retrieve a method's default arguments via Ruby's built-in reflection API.

You can however simply extract the default value into its own method:

```
def default
  'baz'
end

def foo(bar: default)
  p bar: bar, default: default
end

foo
# {:bar=>"baz", :default=>"baz"}

foo(bar: nil)
# {:bar=>nil, :default=>"baz"}
```

In addition, you could make `default` private.

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this:

```
def foo(bar = "baz")
  args = method(__method__).parameters // This will give current methods argument info.
  bar
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only gives the keyword argument names and not the default values.

Comment: This method is interesting, but it only describes required parameters, not their defaults. I thought it might, but nope.